# View generates garbage / (slash) character when rendering

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, variable-assignment, hidden-field

I have an MVC view which is strongly bonded to the model as in the image below.

[image: View bonded with model]

Here in my model, at controller's action, the property `PageAction` was already set to blank.

```
model.PageAction = string.Empty;
```

Now when the action (GET) is called, following  HTML is rendered at client browser:

[image: View rendered as HTML at client browser]

The hidden field `PageAction` is automatically set to `/` (forward slash) character.

> But when quotes are decorated to the scriptlet, while assigning the value to the hidden field, as below:

[image: Quotes decorated on the scriptlet]

the hidden control is rendered as was required in the first place:

[image: Hidden control rendered as required]

I have already checked:

- No javascript is behind the scene i.e. changing or setting the value.
- Control's or property's name is also not responsible.
- Not a browser issue, observed issue with chrome, firefox and IE.

So,

What could be the issue that a garbage `/` (forward slash) is rendered when quotes are not present outside the scriptlet.

Why this behaviour is observed?

Should we always use quotes to assign the values to the HTML controls or is just an issue with the hidden field?

Comment: All attributes should be quoted so not sure why you were not doing it in the first place, but why not just use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PageAction)` anyway (or its aspx equivalent)

Comment: Looks like this slash is part of selfclosing tag, you should use quotes: `value="<%=Model.PageAction%>"`

Comment: @gene-r you are correct, have checked, the browser is considering the closing tag's `/` as value.